# D3 Tree node double click highlights text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree

I have a tree view (similar to http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) except I changed the expand/contract node from a single click to the double click event:

That is, instead of

```
.on("click", function(d) { toggle(d); update(d); });
```

I am using:

```
.on("dblclick", function(d) { toggle(d); update(d); });
```

It functions fine.  The issue is that the double click highlights the text label on the node.  It does not effect the transition, but it is very annoying.  Does anyone know of a way prevent this from happening, other than deleting the node and adding it back at the end of the transition?

BTW, I already tried adding

```
d3.event.preventDefault()
```

inside the double click event, and it did nothing to help.

Comment: Alternatively, cover the text with a div: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058123/d3-tree-node-double-click-highlights-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google returned the following result: 
http://chris-barr.com/index.php/entry/disable_text_selection_with_jquery/

The code on that page is

```
$(function(){
    $.extend($.fn.disableTextSelect = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            if($.browser.mozilla){//Firefox
                $(this).css('MozUserSelect','none');
            }else if($.browser.msie){//IE
                $(this).bind('selectstart',function(){return false;});
            }else{//Opera, etc.
                $(this).mousedown(function(){return false;});
            }
        });
    });
    $('.noSelect').disableTextSelect();//No text selection on elements with a class of 'noSelect'
});
```

In this case, however, you can replace '.noSelect' with '.node', and it should disable text highlighting for all of your nodes.

Comment: I also found the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375056/disable-text-selection-in-chrome about disabling the select effect via CSS, but that option seemed more intrusive if I later wanted to add selection functionality to the page.  It is still a good option to know about.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to disable selection of text completely (which is usually much nicer for the user), you can manually deselect an element via [selectSubString](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__selectSubString).

```
.on("dblclick", function(d) { 
    toggle(d); update(d);
    var text = d3.select(this).select("text")[0][0]
    text.selectSubString(0,0)
});
```

But this does not yet work cross browser since the SVG API is not yet fully implemeted in many cases. (It works in Chrome at least)

A better cross browser way is to just rewrite the text. This usually also kills the selection:

```
g.on("dblclick", function(d) {
    toggle(d); update(d);
    var text = d3.select(this).select("text")
    var value = text.text()
    text.text(value)
})
```

This worked in Firefox and Chrome at least.