# Disabling blue cursor on focus on input elements in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

It seems like chrome specific behaviour on touch devices and should appear after long touch. But I don't need this feature, because I am developing kiosk app.
I've tried 
`-webkit-user-select: none;`
also 
`autocomplete=off`
with no effect
Here is the picture of issue [image: blue cursor]

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375056/disable-text-selection-in-chrome ?

Comment: Are you talking about the outline, or the pointer?

Comment: @jcubic I have no problems with that. I've disabled selection< using `user-select:none`.

Comment: @BryanZwicker I am about caret pointer. or how it is called, that blue rounded thing that looks like a water drop:)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
input[type="text"]:focus {
cursor: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0Lkm5jk/2/

Comment: Thank you for your response. but this does not work. it just removes cursor over input element.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I thought removing the cursor would get rid of the pointer altogether.  Didn't have a mobile device to test it on with me.