# Preventing the selection of text working in IE but not in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-chrome, browser

I've seen a couple different posts regarding preventing the selection of text but for some reason this code prevents selection in IE but not in Chrome..I can't figure out why that is..

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control no-select" name="inputField" placeholder="Select" ng-model="ctrl.ngModelValue">

 .no-select {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* IE/Edge */
  user-select: none;  
}
```

I basically want to prevent the highlighting of the text (ng-model) in the input.

The code above prevents the selection of text when I'm in IE, but for some reason I can still highlight the text in the input element in Chrome? It's usually the other way around when it comes to something working.

Can anybody tell me why this could be and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how to fix this using `css` in `input` field, `user-select: none` rule will apply well in other tags such as `<p>` `<div>` etc.

Here is `JavaScript` solution for you

see [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hnsra6qa/4/)

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('myElement');
inp.addEventListener('select', function() {
  this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd;
}, false);
```

```css
.no-select {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* IE/Edge */
  user-select: none;  
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" id="myElement" class="form-control no-select" name="inputField" placeholder="Select" ng-model="ctrl.ngModelValue">
 
 <p class="no-select">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque quas, illo iste! Obcaecati quisquam, error doloremque, numquam iste, laboriosam possimus nostrum optio aperiam, distinctio quo accusamus cum molestias! Est, at!
 </p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this could work. The one part about it I don't really like is in Chrome it allows me to actually highlight the text but then just removes it when you let the mouse click go the first time, and in IE it allows me to do that same thing every time. I think thats confusing for the user. Is there a way to make it so no highlighting takes place at all and the blinking cursor in the input element never moves. I get that effect with the css 'user-select' in IE but for some reason it doesn't work in chrome. The JS option is fine if I can get the exact same effect . Thanks

Comment: @techer I haven't find any css solution so far or why this is happening in chrome. Lets wait for other answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution that solved it for me:
[Disable Text Selection in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375056/disable-text-selection-in-chrome)

```
   window.onload = function() {
      var element = document.getElementById('content');
      element.onselectstart = function () { return false; } // ie
      element.onmousedown = function () { return false; } // mozilla
 }
```

The above specifies a particular element and disabled the selection of text. Works in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. This works without any css.